# Ruby on Rails - If record is duplicated show the first one created

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, group-by, uniq

In my application, I show websites, new IPs that have visited their site. New IPs will need to be shown as each day & unique.

---

*Example:*

**192.45.11.74 *visited* 12th November**

**192.45.11.74 *visited* 15th November (same user/ip)**

*I don't want to show the visit on 15th November since it's been registered already on 12th November*

---

*This is how I do it:*

```
@visits = Visit.order('started_at DESC').group(:ip)
```

This gives me unique IPs, **but** my problem now is when showing IPs for each date, if an IP has been registered **24th September** and they visit once again **15th October**, instead of not showing that same IP in **15th October** *(because it has been shown on 24th September)*, it adds the new date for the IP and shows it again on **15th October** *(and removes it from **24th September**)*.

*PS: Sorry if it's confusing explained*

How can I prevent that and only show the IPs that has never been registered for each day?

Answer (score 0):

```
@visits = Visit.order('started_at DESC').group(:ip).group_by do |visit| 
  visit.started_at.to_date
end.values.map(&:last)
```